# Maven Build - copy resource from a directory to another directory

Tags: maven, build

I have a project structure like:

> Web Pages
>   |
>   |----WEB-INF
>   |----js
>   |----css
>   |----dist 
>   |----other files

I want to remove all the files and folders except the WEB-INF folder and also copy the contents from dist folder directly into the Web Pages and then remove the dist folder as well during the build process.

I have tried maven-war-plugin but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Is this a Java project? If so than follow the conventions of Maven `src/main/webapp` directory which contains `WEB-INF/` and `js`, `css` etc. I don't understand your `dist` directory ?

Comment: Why do you want to do such remove thing? Want to exclude those from war?

Comment: @khmarbaise dist is the directory that contains the distribution build. ie. r.js optimized version of all the files (css, js, other files). It is a webapp.

Comment: @pirho Yes, I want to exclude them from the war and replace them with the contents from inside the dist directory

Comment: What do you mean by `optimized`? Minimized java script/css files? There are plugins to handle this on the fly...

Comment: Yes, minimized files. I am using r js optimization to achieve this and it works  perfectly. I have a distribution build. I need to selectively provide this distribution build when the war is build.